# Timeout when trying to connect to redshift from node using node-redshift

Tags: node.js, amazon-redshift

I am trying to connect to redshift from my nodejs code to run a code to copy from S3 into redshift.
I am using the node-redshift package for this using the below code.

```
var Redshift = require('node-redshift');
 
var client = {
  user: 'awsuser',
  database: 'dev',
  password: 'zxxxx',
  port: '5439',
  host: 'redshift-cluster-1.xxxxxxxxxx.us-east-1.redshift.amazonaws.com',
};

var redshiftClient = new Redshift(client);
var pg_query = "copy test1 from 's3://aws-bucket/" + file_name + "ACCESS_KEY_ID 'xxxxxxx' SECRET_ACCESS_KEY 'xxxxxxxxxx';";
redshiftClient.query(pg_query, {raw: true}, function (err1, pgres) {
 if (err1) {
              console.log('error here');
              console.error(err1);
 } else {
            //upload successful
      console.log('success');
       }
 });
   }
    });
```

I have tried using explicit connect also but in any case I am getting the timeout error as below
Error: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT XXX.XX.XX.XX:5439

The redshift cluster is assigned to a role for S3 full access and also has the default security group assigned.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your cluster is publicly visible. The cluster should be sitting in a certain subnet. For that subnet, the security groups' inbound rules in VPC should have an entry that states that all IPs are allowed to connect to your Redshift cluster on port 5439.

If your public IP is present in that set then only you can connect to the cluster.

Say you have SQL Workbench/J which allows you to connect to the redshift cluster. If you are able to connect with this SQL client, you can ignore the above matter because it means that your IP is able to connect to the redshift cluster via SQL Workbench/J.